# Histogram Computation in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to compute image histogram in VHDL. I have 24 bit intensity values and since the intensity levels are too many, I have to create bins(1920 max). 
I am having troubles in comparing the intensity value for every incoming pixel and deciding bin value, so that I can use the bin value as an address and update the count in a BRAM.

I get an error while simulation : Iteration limit reached

If there is a different way to compute the bins please let me know. Thanks!

declaration--

```
signal data_in : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
signal bin : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
signal s_data_in : integer ;
signal s_binsize : integer :=2048;
signal s_bin : integer  ;
signal s_bincount : integer :=0 ;
signal s_temp: integer :=2048;

p_clk: process
begin
  s_clk <= '0';
  while (s_SimuDone /= 'H') loop
     wait for C_CLOCK_PERIOD/2;
     s_clk <= not s_clk;
  end loop;
  wait;
end process p_clk;

stimulus: process 
begin
  data_in <= x"0000ff";
  wait for C_CLOCK_PERIOD*10;
  data_in <= x"00000f";
  wait for C_CLOCK_PERIOD*10;
  data_in <= x"000fff";
  wait for C_CLOCK_PERIOD*10;
  data_in <= x"0fffff";
  wait;
end process stimulus;
s_data_in <= to_integer(unsigned (data_in));
bin <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(s_bin, 12));

process (s_data_in, s_bincount)
begin
    if (s_data_in < s_binsize) then
        s_bin <= 0;
    else if (s_data_in < s_temp) then
            s_bin <= s_bincount;
            s_bincount <= 0;
            s_temp <= 2048;
         else
            s_bincount <= s_bincount + 1;
            s_temp <= s_temp + s_binsize;
         end if;       
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the answer you're looking for but I just want to say that the second process should really be in a separate entity since that will be part of your RTL which you will synthesize. This is unless you want to create the histogram as part of your test bench. But even then....

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I did it separately, but to show it here I did that so. I want to be able to find the address in one clock cycle so I cannot add clk there.

Comment: ok i deleted the old answer and added a new one. You don't even need a process because all you want is to divide data_in by 2048.

Comment: The correct writing of `else if` is `elsif`. Your algorithm defines a combinatoric loop and processes all input in the same physical time while consuming thousands of delta-cycles. Even in simulation, you need a clocked process to allow time to pass by.

Answer (score 0):

The error has to do with too many iterations in one simulation delta due to the statement `s_bincount <= s_bincount + 1`. The clock needs to be specified since the design is synchronous.
But to do just what you need you can change the testbench to the following:

```
signal data_in : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
signal bin : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
signal s_data_in : integer ;
signal s_binsize : integer :=2048;
signal s_bin : integer  ;
signal s_bincount : integer :=0 ;
signal s_temp: integer :=2048;

p_clk: process
begin
  s_clk <= '0';
  while (s_SimuDone /= 'H') loop
     wait for C_CLOCK_PERIOD/2;
     s_clk <= not s_clk;
  end loop;
  wait;
end process p_clk;

stimulus: process 
begin
  data_in <= x"0000ff";
  wait for C_CLOCK_PERIOD*10;
  data_in <= x"00000f";
  wait for C_CLOCK_PERIOD*10;
  data_in <= x"000fff";
  wait for C_CLOCK_PERIOD*10;
  data_in <= x"0fffff";
  wait;
end process stimulus;
s_data_in <= to_integer(unsigned (data_in));

bin <= data_in(22 downto 11);
```

You can make **bin** a clocked variable if you wish but you don't need to in this case. 
Also **bin** should really be 13 bits, not 12.

Please simulate this and let me know.

Comment: The error has to do with too many iterations in one simulation delta due to the statement `s_bincount <= s_bincount + 1`. The clock needs to be specified since the design is synchronous.